# Insert em duas tabelas no SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, transações, sql-insert, chave-estrangeira

Como faço para adicionar dados em duas tabelas no Android em uma única transação?

Tenho duas tabelas Cliente e Endereco, está última com uma chave estrangeira referenciando a tabela cliente, e deve ser cadastrado em uma única transação. Sei que no MySQL tem a função `LAST_INSERT_ROWID();`. E no Android SQLite como faço?

Answer (score 3):

Para obter o  *id* do último registo inserido use o valor retornado pela função `SQLiteDatabase.insert()`

```
long id = myDb.insert(...);
```

Para fazer vários *inserts* em uma única transação:

```
myDb.beginTransaction();
try {
    //inserir cliente e guardar o id gerado
    long id = myDb.insert(...);

    //Componha o registo endereço usado o id
    .........
    //inserir endereço
    myDb.insert(...);

    //Commit da transação
    myDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
}catch {
    //Erro durante a transação 
}finally {
    myDb.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado!
Com sua dica consegui resolver.